# properties of fundamental solution as a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

> $(a)$ Let $\displaystyle L=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}D^\alpha$ be
> a differential operator with constant coefficients such that $L$ has a
> fundamental solution $E$ which is $C^\infty$ on
> $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ . Let $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
> with $\phi\equiv1$ in a neighborhood of zero . Show that $P=\phi E$ is
> a distribution with compact support and such that $L(P)=\delta+\zeta$
> for $\zeta\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ .
>
> $(b)$ Deduce that if $T\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $L(T)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $T\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ .
>
> $(c)$ Deduce that every fundamental solution of $L$ is $C^\infty$ on
> $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ .

$(a)$ It is easy to prove $\phi E=(\phi E)_f$ for some $f\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $f\equiv1$ on $\text{supp}(\phi)$ . Hence $P$ is of compact support . Moreover \begin{align*}L(P)&=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}D^\alpha(\phi E)\\&=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\alpha{\alpha\choose k}(D^{\alpha-k}\phi)(D^kE)\\&=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-1}{\alpha\choose k}(D^{\alpha-k}\phi)(D^kE)+\phi\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}D^\alpha E\\&=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-1}{\alpha\choose k}(D^{\alpha-k}\phi)(D^kE)+\delta\end{align*} since $L(E)=\delta$ and $\phi\equiv1$ in a neighborhood of zero . But I don't see why $\displaystyle\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-1}{\alpha\choose k}(D^{\alpha-k}\phi)(D^kE)\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that it may serve for $\zeta$ .

$(b)$ and $(c)$ are not clear to me how to proceed . Any help is appreciated .

Comment: For (a), just write $P=\phi E= (\phi-1) E +E$ and apply $L$. Note that $(\phi-1)E$ is a smooth function since $\phi-1$ vanishes in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: For (b) you can assume that $T$ has compact support. Then write $T=\delta\ast T=(L(P)-\zeta)\ast T= L(P)\ast T -\zeta\ast T=P\ast L(T) -\zeta\ast T$.

Comment: For (c), note that $L(F-E)=0$ and apply (b).